# Postgres Table Join Added Additional Rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I noticed that the number of rows has increased after running the queries below.
The table `data.consolidated_billing_journal` has about 15,883,000 rows but the result of this query was 15,900,000 rows.

I had taken care such that all joined tables `cluster_profit_center(profit_center)`, `cname_fixed_match(cname)` are joined on their primary keys, hence no duplicate.

```
    SELECT l.*, cl0, cl1, cl2, cl_tag, std_cname
    FROM data.consolidated_billing_journal l        
    LEFT JOIN ref.cluster_profit_center cpc
    ON l.cluster_profit_center = cpc.profit_center
    LEFT JOIN cname.cname_fixed_match cfm
    ON l.cust_acc_name = cfm.cname OR l.billing_acc_name = cfm.cname
```

What could be the reason where additional rows were added? I'm imagining it to be similar to Excel VLOOKUP where the fact table remains with fixed number of rows.

Comment: One of the other tables has several rows matching for a consolidated_billing_journal  row.

Comment: is that possible if the matching are against primary keys, thus guaranteed unique?

Comment: I assume l.cluster_profit_center is unique, but perhaps cpc.profit_center isn't.

Comment: potentially the issue is the last statement, since there is OR condition. How do I make sure the matching stop if first condition satisfied?

Comment: Throw in AND cpc.profit_center IS NULL.